# How to use setChecked in onsen SwitchView

Tags: onsen-ui

I have used ons-switchView in my list as follows:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="item" class="list__item__line-height">
    Switch View <ons-switch modifier="list-item" var="switchView" ng-click='onSwitchViewClick()'></ons-switch>
</ons-list-item>
```

and in my controller, I want to try something as follows:

```
if (localStorageService.get('switchView') === 'grid') {
    $scope.switchView.setChecked(true);
}
else {
    $scope.switchView.setChecked(false);
}
```

However, I got some error stating that error of undefined. I guess something must be wrong here:

```
$scope.switchView.setChecked(true);
```

But I cannot get it work. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to access switch, from the controller, before it gets initialized on the DOM, that's why you are getting undefined error.

Here is a working [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/EjoxOY). and the relative code.

In your case, the code should be something like(I used a button to check the value, but you can also do it dynamically):

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <ons-list-item modifier="item" class="list__item__line-height">
    <ons-switch var="switch"></ons-switch>
    <ons-button ng-click="checkSwitch()">Check switch status</ons-button>
  </ons-list-item>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```js
ons.bootstrap()

.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.checkSwitch = function() {
    if(localStorageService.get('switchView') === 'grid') 
      $scope.switch.setChecked(true);
    else
      $scope.switch.setChecked(false);
  };
});
```

Comment: So you mean method setChecked as mentioned in http://onsen.io/reference/ons-switch.html#methods-summary cannot be used?

Comment: Yes they can be used, but I guess you are trying to access switch, from the controller, before it gets initialized on the DOM, that's why you are getting undefined error

Comment: @Rafita I edited my answer, using the same functions that you want to use

Comment: thank, but is it possible to use something like .controller('MyController', function ($scope) { $scope.switch.setChecked(true); }); ? The thing is I want to set check or not based on a certain value when the page is loaded.

Comment: no, because you'll try to access the switch before it has been created, you can use ons.ready() for that, which executes the code once the DOM has been fully loaded (http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onsreadyfunction)

If my answer helped you, please consider to upvote it ad to mark it as best answer, so users that will have the same problem in future will be able to find a solution more easily